# Desperately need help on a transformation logic

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table named PROF, from which i need to take certain codes which are laid from x1..x20 and y1..y20 (all together 40 columns) which needs to be checked in another table CROSSREF table for reference codes. The problem here is there is one to many mapping in this CROSSREF table.

```
table PROF
---------

mem_id cl_id line_no x1..x20 y1..y20

table CROSSREF
--------------
refx    refy
```

here x1 is compared with z1 in refx and reference value in refy field needs to be pulled out which has 1 to many relationship..

for eg:

```
refx  refy
---------- 
z1  -> a1
       a3
       a2
z2  -> a10
       a50
```

so here for x1 from table PROF, I have a1,a2, a3 codes. as per the requirement, 
a1 moved to x1, a3 to x2 and a2 to x3. and need to fill in till x20.. I think first I will have to pull values till i can accomodate till x1..x20 by looking into CROSSREF table and leave the rest of codes in PROF table if im not able to accomodate.

Final transformation

```
x1 -> a1
x2 -> a3
x3 -> a2
x4 -> a10
x5 -> a20 and so on
```

I know its too complex, i have told suggestions to change the CROSSREF to one to one mapping, but the requirement is not changed so far.

Comment: Made use of nested table to store the values of refy on comparison with PROF table x1,x2,,x20, then removed the duplicates among the refy values if any using MULTISET and then updates the values back into x1,x2..x20.

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of fiddling, I think I found the answer. Assuming I understand your question correctly.

The answer below uses

1. [UNPIVOT](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1) :(which is available in Oracle 11g that you tagged), in order to transpose columns x1, .. y20 into rows (40 rows).
2. [WITH](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause) clause: In order to join the two tables.

Since there no common column to join the two tables, I used `rownum`

```
WITH q1 AS 
( 
       SELECT xy, 
              ROWNUM r 
       FROM   prof unpivot (xy FOR x IN (x1, 
                                         x2, 
                                         x3 , 
                                         x4, 
                                         x5  --add rest of the columns here
                                           ))), 
q2 AS 
( 
         SELECT   refx, 
                  refy, 
                  ROWNUM r 
         FROM     crossref 
         ORDER BY refx, 
                  refy) 
SELECT     q1.xy, 
           q2.refy 
FROM       q1 
inner join q2 
ON         q1.r = q2.r;
```

Here [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8f90/1)

The result for the first 5 rows:

[image]

Comment: the common field between the 2 tables are refx and x1..x20, y1..y20.. so each x1 needs to be compared with refx value and corresponding refy needs to be pulled out which many contain one to many rows.                              which i showed in the example

Comment: @blackpanther May I understand what is wrong with the result I posted just now? Is not the same you posted as 'Final Transformation'?

Comment: im expecting something like Emil Moise, mentioned.. I have also added comment in detail there for that answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to move values from crossref table into prof table. If so, you can use a cursor to iterate through crossref values and use a switch statement to do the inserts:

```
begin
  for r_crossref in (select refx, refy from crossref) loop
    case r_crossref.refx
      when 'z1' insert into prof (x1) values (r_crossref.refy);
      when 'z2' insert into prof (x2) values (r_crossref.refy);
      ...
    end case;
  end loop;
end;
/
commit;
```

Update based on owner's feedback. If my assumption is correct, you need to insert one row for each zN group into PROF table and update all xN values for that corresponding row, so the solution below would work. Still, the problem seems a bit odd, or at least we don't have enough info about it. For example, what will happen if you will have more than 20 rows in CROSSREF table for one particular zN value and so on...

```
begin
  for r_crossref_refx in (select distinct refx from crossref) loop
    insert into prof(SOME_MEM_ID_BASED_ON_YOUR_BUSINESS_LOGIC, ...) values (...);
    for r_crossref_refy in (select refy from crossref where refx = r_crossref_refx.refx) loop
      case r_crossref.refy
        when 'z1' update prof set x1 = r_crossref_refy.refy where mem_id = SOME_MEM_ID_BASED_ON_YOUR_BUSINESS_LOGIC;
        when 'z2' update prof set x2 = r_crossref_refy.refy where mem_id = SOME_MEM_ID_BASED_ON_YOUR_BUSINESS_LOGIC;
        ...
      end case;
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/
commit;
```

Comment: i need to check the for each value of x1, x2... till x20  in PROF table with CROSSREF refx value and take refy.. in my case for one refx there are many refy. shown in the example.. i need to take those multiple values too.. and try to frame a new set of x1,x2,x3.. with values as shown in for eg. and final transformation and finally update these new sets into PROF table for that cl_id,mem_id and line_no

Comment: I've updated my answer but in case I've correctly understood your issue, there are still some business logic problems that you'll need to handle on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Made use of nested table to store the values of refy on comparison with PROF table x1,x2,,x20, then removed the duplicates among the refy values if any using MULTISET and then updated the values back into x1,x2..x20 of the PROF table.

Used IMPLICIT cursor, Nested table, MULTISET - to combine each set and remove duplicates among them and built the final set that needs to be updated back as shown in the final transformation..

Thanks to the friends who helped me do this and also to @Hawk and @EmilMoise